# Fixed tabs with ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager in my Android application, but I'm more worried, that the tabs are swipeable. I want tabs like Google playstore, it shows 3 or 4 tabs by default, and then tab slides only after 3rd tab.

How can I achieve that kind of Tabs with Viewpager ?

Comment: You'll have to make custom Tabs for that. **OR** you can simply use a library [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check swipe tabs basic project from here: http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html

And download sample source code from here: http://developer.android.com/downloads/samples/SlidingTabsBasic.zip

Also this is a useful library which I use in my projects:
https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

You should set your pager's tab strip's view attribute

```
pstsShouldExpand=true
```

I hope this'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't for the life of me work out how to do this without an external library, i ended up going with https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip.

Quite easy to implement

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new yourViewPagerAdapter()));

    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    tabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    tabs.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
```